# I need to move down CheckBox a bit

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

[image]
My intention is to have the checkbox aligned in the middle of Input and Button.
I try to use class align-center in "form-check" but not work.
Can anyone suggest a way for me?
This below is my code.

```
<form method="get" asp-controller="Permit" asp-action="FindPermitNumber" class="row g-3 mt-3">   
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.searchText))
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" name="searchText" />
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" value="@Model.searchText" name="searchText" />
    </div>
}

<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="autoSizingCheck" name="isActive" asp-for="@Model.isActive">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="autoSizingCheck">
            Cancel
        </label>
    </div>
</div>       

<div class="col-md-3">
    <button formmethod="get" class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="Permit" asp-action="FindPermitNumber"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass fa-lg"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI I've removed the irrelevant tags from your question. Please only tag your questions with tags that are directly related to it. Even though this is a Razor template, it's still basically just HTML and CSS, so that aspect is irrelevant to the answers you require. You've not shown any JQuery code either, so it doesn't seem that JQuery is related to your question either. I've also removed that.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the [`.align-items-center`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/#inline-forms) class to your `form.row` :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form method="get" class="row g-3 mt-3 align-items-center">   
  <div class="col-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
      <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="autoSizingCheck" />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="autoSizingCheck">
              Cancel
          </label>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```